# Can this haskell sample be shorter?

Tags: haskell

This is my solution to exercise from YAHT:

> Exercise 4.6 Write a datatype Tuple which can hold one, two, three or
>   four elements, depending on the constructor (that is, there should be
>   four constructors, one for each number of arguments). Also provide
>   functions tuple1 through tuple4 which take a tuple and return Just the
>   value in that position, or Nothing if the number is in valid (i.e.,
>   you ask for the tuple4 on a tuple holding only two elements).

When I wrote a first line I was excited about simplicity comparing to C#

```
    data Tuplex a b c d = Tuple1 a | Tuple2 a b | Tuple3 a b c | Tuple4 a b c d

    -- class Tuplex<a,b,c,d> {
    --       Tuplex(a p1){ _p1 = p1; }
    --       Tuplex(a p1, b p2){ _p1 = p1; _p2 = p2; }
    --       Tuplex(a p1, b p2, c p3){ _p1 = p1; _p2 = p2; _p3 = p3; }
    --       Tuplex(a p1, b p2, c p3, d p4){ _p1 = p1; _p2 = p2; _p3 = p3; _p4 = p4; }
    --       public Nullable<a> _p1;
    --       public Nullable<b> _p2;
    --       public Nullable<c> _p3;
    --       public Nullable<d> _p4;
    -- }
```

In C# I can access any field without problem, but here I should write an 'accessor functions', right? And amount of code here makes me sad.

Can I have shorter code here?

```
    tuple1 ∷ Tuplex a b c d → Maybe a
    tuple2 ∷ Tuplex a b c d → Maybe b
    tuple3 ∷ Tuplex a b c d → Maybe c
    tuple4 ∷ Tuplex a b c d → Maybe d
    tuple1 (Tuple1 a) = Just a
    tuple1 (Tuple2 a b) = Just a
    tuple1 (Tuple3 a b c) = Just a
    tuple1 (Tuple4 a b c d) = Just a
    tuple2 (Tuple1 a) = Nothing
    tuple2 (Tuple2 a b) = Just b
    tuple2 (Tuple3 a b c) = Just b
    tuple2 (Tuple4 a b c d) = Just b
    tuple3 (Tuple1 a) = Nothing
    tuple3 (Tuple2 a b) = Nothing
    tuple3 (Tuple3 a b c) = Just c
    tuple3 (Tuple4 a b c d) = Just c
    tuple4 (Tuple1 a) = Nothing
    tuple4 (Tuple2 a b) = Nothing
    tuple4 (Tuple3 a b c) = Nothing
    tuple4 (Tuple4 a b c d) = Just d

    -- unit tests
    prop_tx1 = tuple1 (Tuple1 4) ≡ Just 4
    prop_tx2 = tuple1 (Tuple2 4 'q') ≡ Just 4
    prop_tx3 = tuple2 (Tuple1 4) ≡ (Nothing ∷ Maybe Char)
    prop_tx4 = tuple2 (Tuple2 4 'q') ≡ Just 'q'
```

Comment: BTW one of C# advantages here is Maybe compared to Nullable<T>. In C# we have special syntax (? postfix) and completely transparent (but still optionally controllable) conversion between T? and T (int? and int). Even during unboxing, I can have object x = 5; var y = (int?)x. Not mentioning about needless conversion from int b = 5; to int? c = b;

Comment: Oh, so many answers and ways... And you know what? Nothing is readable enough if we take in account an amount of knowledge that author gives in YAHT at that exercise point, except for 1st Daniel's answer... Sure, further reading can bring some light on 'where' or '>>=' or '>=>' operators... But even this answer is quite complex, I think, I wouldn't guess that by my self, seems tricky :) Thank you for answers a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try to keep it dead simple:

```
data Tuplex a b c d = Tuple1 a | Tuple2 a b | Tuple3 a b c | Tuple4 a b c d

toMaybes (Tuple1 p)       = (Just p, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
toMaybes (Tuple2 p q)     = (Just p, Just  q, Nothing, Nothing)
toMaybes (Tuple3 p q r)   = (Just p, Just  q, Just  r, Nothing)
toMaybes (Tuple4 p q r s) = (Just p, Just  q, Just  r, Just  s)

tuple1 t = p where (p,_,_,_) = toMaybes t 
tuple2 t = q where (_,q,_,_) = toMaybes t 
tuple3 t = r where (_,_,r,_) = toMaybes t 
tuple4 t = s where (_,_,_,s) = toMaybes t
```

Comment: It looks simpler and understandable but at the point of reading this book I'm unfamiliar with 'where' operator

Comment: This is the same as `tuple1 t = let (p,_,_,_) = toMaybes t in p`. In most cases you can see `where` as a kind of "reversed `let`". There are some differences regarding scopes etc, though.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way: centralize your pattern match.

```
unTuplex f1 f2 f3 f4 t = case t of
    Tuple1 a       -> f1 a
    Tuple2 a b     -> f2 a b
    Tuple3 a b c   -> f3 a b c
    Tuple4 a b c d -> f4 a b c d

tuple1 = unTuplex (\a -> Just a ) (\a _ -> Just a ) (\a _ _ -> Just a ) (\a _ _ _ -> Just a)
tuple2 = unTuplex (\_ -> Nothing) (\_ b -> Just b ) (\_ b _ -> Just b ) (\_ b _ _ -> Just b)
tuple3 = unTuplex (\_ -> Nothing) (\_ _ -> Nothing) (\_ _ c -> Just c ) (\_ _ c _ -> Just c)
tuple4 = unTuplex (\_ -> Nothing) (\_ _ -> Nothing) (\_ _ _ -> Nothing) (\_ _ _ d -> Just d)
```

Alternately, you could explicitly express the nested structure:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
data DONE = DONE -- could just use (), but this is a pretty descriptive name
type Tuplex a b c d = Maybe (a, Maybe (b, Maybe (c, Maybe (d, DONE))))

tuple1 x = x >>= return . fst -- or tuple1 = fmap fst
tuple2 x = x >>= tuple1 . snd
tuple3 x = x >>= tuple2 . snd
tuple4 x = x >>= tuple3 . snd
```

Then `tuple1` has (among others) the type `Tuplex a b c d -> Maybe a`, and on up to `tuple4` which has (again, among others) the type `Tuplex a b c d -> Maybe d`.

edit: ...actually, this suggests an alternate continuation of the first approach.

```
import Control.Monad

decrement :: Tuplex a b c d -> Maybe (Tuplex b c d t)
decrement (Tuple1 a) = Nothing
decrement (Tuple2 a b) = Just (Tuple1 b)
decrement (Tuple3 a b c) = Just (Tuple2 b c)
decrement (Tuple4 a b c d) = Just (Tuple3 b c d)

zero :: Tuplex a b c d -> a
zero (Tuple1 a) = a
zero (Tuple2 a b) = a
zero (Tuple3 a b c) = a
zero (Tuple4 a b c d) = a

tuple1 = Just . zero
tuple2 = decrement >=> tuple1
tuple3 = decrement >=> tuple2
tuple4 = decrement >=> tuple3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give your tuples field names!

```
data Tuplex a b c d = Tuple1 { tuple1 :: a }
                    | Tuple2 { tuple1 :: a
                             , tuple2 :: b }
                    | Tuple3 { tuple1 :: a
                             , tuple2 :: b
                             , tuple3 :: c }
                    | Tuple4 { tuple1 :: a
                             , tuple2 :: b
                             , tuple3 :: c
                             , tuple4 :: d }
```

And as a result you have functions with types of:

```
tuple1 :: Tuplex a b c d -> a
tuple2 :: Tuplex a b c d -> b
-- etc
```

Using field names of records like this is actually less common than you might expect in Haskell due to the ease of pattern matching and, in at least some circles, the popularity of the `RecordWildCard` extension which allows you to do things like:

```
function (Tuples3 {..}) =
-- now you have variables tuple1 :: a, tuple2 :: b, etc.
```

(when using record wild cards it might be better to name your tuple fields something a bit simpler, like tupA, tupB, tupC, tupD)

Comment: The other problem, at least in this example, is that the accessor functions are partial. Something like `tuple2 (Tuple1 "foo")` would break. In this particular case--and in most normal code, I imagine--you want some more elegant way to handle invalid accesses like that (e.g. returning a `Maybe` as specified in the question).

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice he used `Maybe`.   The `derive` tool can probably do that and if not then it should be patched. Also, there's little difference to his use and a `data Tup a b c d = Tup { tA :: (Maybe a), tB ::  (Maybe b) ... }` (plus some helper functions/constructors) so perhaps that would be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Safe (atMay) -- from the 'safe' package

toList (Tuple1 a) = [a]
toList (Tuple2 a b) = [a, b]
toList (Tuple3 a b c) = [a, b, c]
toList (Tuple4 a b c d) = [a, b, c, d]

tuple n t = atMay (toList t) n

[tuple1, tuple2, tuple3, tuple4] = map tuple [1..4]
```

Edit: Vitus correctly point out that this only works for a homogeneous tuple, so this is not a correct answer.  In that case I defer to Daniel's answer.

Comment: If you don't want to use an external package for whatever reason, you could also do something like `listToMaybe . drop n`.

Comment: Mind you that `tuple1 :: TupleX a a a a -> Maybe a` and not the more generic `TupleX a b c d -> Maybe a`.